How can I solve $\sum_{i=1}^{M-1} (M+i)^{M+i+1/2}/i^{i+1/2}$?
I am trying to solve an equation in Mathematica:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{M-1} \frac{(M+i)^{M+i+\frac{1}{2}}}{i^{i+\frac{1}{2}}} 
$$
Does a general solution exist for this expression?
And if $M \to \infty$, can this expression be solved in integral form or something similar?
Numerical analysis method is not needed.

This is not a  equation ?
I doubt there's a closed form for the series.For now only can be computed numerically.

like Mariusz says, an equation has to have = in it.  (in Mathematica syntax this is == also you should indicate what is it you are solving for.

An example: f[M_] := Sum[(M + i)^(M + i + 1/2)/i^(i + 1/2), {i, 1, M - 1}]; f[3] gives: 512 + (3125 Sqrt[5/2])/4

Isn't it obvious that as M→∞ the sum diverges to infinity?

A very good approximation is to take the last term of the sum and take it asymptotic expansion $2^{2 m-\frac{1}{2}} m^m$

@yarchik your suggestion is off by a factor of 2, see my answer.

@Roman Can well be, but I explain how to get my approximation. As far as I see, your approximation is just a guess.

A pretty good approximation (without proof) is
$$
f_m \approx e^{-\sqrt{2}} 2^{2 m+\frac12} \left(m+\sqrt{2}\right)^m
$$
Try it out:
f[m_] := Sum[(i+m)^(m+i+1/2)/i^(i+1/2), {i, m-1}]
g[m_] = 2^(2*m+1/2) (m+Sqrt[2])^m Exp[-Sqrt[2]];

{f[100], g[100]} // N
(*    {2.25008*10^260, 2.25015*10^260}    *)

{f[1000], g[1000]} // N
(*    {1.622080123879442*10^3602, 1.622080637904872*10^3602}    *)

Simpler, but less accurate: $f_m\approx 2^{2m+\frac12} m^m$:
f[m_] := Sum[(i+m)^(m+i+1/2)/i^(i+1/2), {i, m-1}]
h[m_] = 2^(2m+1/2) * m^m;

{f[100], h[100]} // N
(*    {2.25008*10^260, 2.27255*10^260}    *)

{f[1000], h[1000]} // N
(*    {1.622080123879442*10^3602, 1.623702000633702*10^3602}    *)


Not realy an answer:
$$\sum _{i=1}^{M-1} \frac{(M+i)^{M+i+\frac{1}{2}}}{i^{i+\frac{1}{2}}}=\\\sum _{i=1}^{M-1} i^M
   \left(1+\frac{M}{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}+i+M}\\\approx\sum _{i=1}^{M-1} i^M \underset{i\to \infty
   }{\text{lim}}\left(1+\frac{M}{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}+i+M}=\sum _{i=1}^{M-1} i^M \exp (M)=e^M
   H_{-1+M}^{(-M)}$$
if $M\to \infty$
f[M_] := N[Sum[(M + i)^(M + i + 1/2)/i^(i + 1/2), {i, 1, M - 1}], 20];
g[M_] := N[E^M  HarmonicNumber[-1 + M, -M], 20];
Table[{f[2^m], g[2^m]}, {m, 3, 11}] // TableForm


